# Call to Node module failed with error: Prerendering failed because of error: Error: Cannot find module "ngx-treeview" at webpackMissingModule?

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, node-modules

I have create an angular app using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates --> MVC ASP.NET Core with Angular.

package.json of my unit test project has following modules:

```
 "dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "4.1.2",
  "@angular/common": "4.1.2",
  "@angular/compiler": "4.1.2",
  "@angular/core": "4.1.2",
  "@angular/forms": "4.1.2",
  "@angular/http": "4.1.2",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.2",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.2",
  "@angular/platform-server": "4.1.2",
  "@angular/router": "4.1.2",
  "@types/node": "7.0.18",
  "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
  "aspnet-prerendering": "^2.0.5",
  "aspnet-webpack": "^1.0.29",
  "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.1.3",
  "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta",
  "css": "2.2.1",
  "css-loader": "0.28.1",
  "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
  "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
  "expose-loader": "0.7.3",
  "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.0",
  "file-loader": "0.11.1",
  "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
  "html-loader": "0.4.5",
  "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
  "jquery": "3.2.1",
  "json-loader": "0.5.4",
  "lodash": "^4.17.4",
  "ngx-treeview": "^1.2.3",
  "preboot": "4.5.2",
  "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
  "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
  "rxjs": "5.4.0",
  "source-map-loader": "^0.2.1",
  "style-loader": "0.17.0",
  "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
  "typescript": "2.3.2",
  "url-loader": "0.5.8",
  "webpack": "2.5.1",
  "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.0",
  "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
  "zone.js": "0.8.10"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
  "@types/chai": "3.5.2",
  "@types/jasmine": "2.5.47",
  "chai": "3.5.0",
  "jasmine-core": "2.6.1",
  "karma": "1.7.0",
  "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.1.1",
  "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
  "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
  "karma-webpack": "2.0.3"
 }
}
```

I have install the node module ngx-treeview and it is present in node_modules folder.

Now the application modules file has imported the treeviewModule:

```
    import { NgModule} from '@angular/core'; import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router'; import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

    import { TreeviewModule } from 'ngx-treeview';

    import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component' import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';



    export const sharedConfig: NgModule = {
        bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
        declarations: [
            AppComponent,
            HomeComponent,

        ],  imports: [      TreeviewModule,
            RouterModule.forRoot([
                { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
                { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent }

            ]),         
FormsModule,        
HttpModule,     
],  exports: 
[       
FormsModule     ] };
```

When i bundle it with webpack i get the following error:

command is: webpack --config webpack.config.js

Error is:

```
    ERROR in ./ClientApp/app/app.module.shared.ts
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ngx-treeview' in 'D:\WS\Source\App\ClientApp\app'
     @ ./ClientApp/app/app.module.shared.ts 6:21-44
     @ ./ClientApp/app/app.module.server.ts
     @ ./ClientApp/boot-server.ts
```

The webpack.config.js is:

```
    const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;

module.exports = (env) => {
    // Configuration in common to both client-side and server-side bundles
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    const sharedConfig = {
        stats: { modules: false },
        context: __dirname,
        resolve: { extensions: [ '.js', '.ts' ] },
        output: {
            filename: '[name].js',
            publicPath: '/dist/' // Webpack dev middleware, if enabled, handles requests for this URL prefix
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.ts$/, include: /ClientApp/, use: ['awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true', 'angular2-template-loader'] },
                { test: /\.html$/, use: 'html-loader?minimize=false' },
                { test: /\.css$/, use: [ 'to-string-loader', isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' ] },
                { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [new CheckerPlugin()]
    };

    // Configuration for client-side bundle suitable for running in browsers
    const clientBundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';
    const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        entry: { 'main-client': './ClientApp/boot-client.ts' },
        output: { path: path.join(__dirname, clientBundleOutputDir) },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
            // Plugins that apply in development builds only
            new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
                filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
                moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(clientBundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
            })
        ] : [
            // Plugins that apply in production builds only
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
        ])
    });

    // Configuration for server-side (prerendering) bundle suitable for running in Node
    const serverBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        resolve: { mainFields: ['main'] },
        entry: { 'main-server': './ClientApp/boot-server.ts' },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./ClientApp/dist/vendor-manifest.json'),
                sourceType: 'commonjs2',
                name: './vendor'
            })
        ],
        output: {
            libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
            path: path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp/dist')
        },
        target: 'node',
        devtool: 'source-map'
    });

    return [clientBundleConfig, serverBundleConfig];
};
```

I see that the vendor.manifest.json does not have an entry for the ngx-treeview node module.

Can anyone help me how to solve this error:

```
 ERROR in ./ClientApp/app/app.module.shared.ts
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ngx-treeview' in 'D:\WS\Source\App\ClientApp\app'
     @ ./ClientApp/app/app.module.shared.ts 6:21-44
     @ ./ClientApp/app/app.module.server.ts
     @ ./ClientApp/boot-server.ts
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try

import { TreeviewModule } from 'ngx-treeview/src';